# Panic while deserializing JSON data

Tags: json, api, rust, serde, serde-json

I'm currently trying to use some API keys to access the Kucoin exchange from my program.I want to be able to have a global initialization of the keys so I can reuse them as credentials in different functions and modules.

I store the keys in a `credentials.json` file that looks like this:

```
[{
  "name": "",
  "api_key": "",
  "api_secret": "",
  "api_pass": ""
}, {
  "name": "",
  "api_key": "",
  "api_secret": "",
  "api_pass": ""
}]
```

And then go ahead and try to deserialize the json into a format that I can use with my functions, like so:

```
use kucoin_rs::{serde_json, serde_derive::{Serialize, Deserialize}};

static  CREDENTIALS_JSON: &'static str = include_str!("./credentials.json");

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct ApiCredentials {
    pub(crate) name: String,
    pub(crate) api_key: String,
    pub(crate) api_secret: String,
    pub(crate) api_pass: String,
}

pub fn load_api_credentials() -> ApiCredentials {
  
    let deserialize_creds = serde_json::from_str::<ApiCredentials(&CREDENTIALS_JSON).expect("Error deserializing JSON data");
    deserialize_creds
    
}
```

The code compiles when I run `cargo check`, but panics when I `cargo run`.The error message reads

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error deserializing JSON data: Error("invalid type: map, expected a string", line: 1, column: 1)'
```

The message says that it expects a string, so I try to parse `CREDENTIALS_JSON` as string like so:

```
 let deserialize_creds = serde_json::from_str::<ApiCredentials>(&CREDENTIALS_JSON.to_string()).expect("Unable to deserialize credentials.json!");
```

But I still get the same error, what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` is a list of credentials.
Deserialize it into a `Vec` like this:

```rust
pub fn load_api_credentials() -> Vec<ApiCredentials> {
    let deserialize_creds = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<ApiCredentials>>(&CREDENTIALS_JSON).expect("Error deserializing JSON data");
    deserialize_creds
}
```

Or return the first one:

```rust
pub fn load_api_credentials() -> ApiCredentials {
    let mut deserialize_creds = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<ApiCredentials>>(&CREDENTIALS_JSON).expect("Error deserializing JSON data");
    deserialize_creds.swap_remove(0)
}
```

Comment: I've gone with the second example because the function returns `APiCredentials`, which is what I want instead of a vector of `APiCredentials`. It works just fine! Thanks, soo much!